# Subscript out of range, does not enter the loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function APortfolioReturnsXL1(Returns As Range, Weights As Range) As Double()

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim arrReturns() As Double
    Dim arrWeights() As Double
    Dim TotRows As Double
    Dim TotCols As Double
    Dim RowCtr As Double
    Dim Colctr As Double
    Dim WgtColctr As Double
    Dim WgtRows As Double

    TotRows = Returns.Rows.Count
    TotCols = Returns.Columns.Count

    WgtRows = Weights.Rows.Count

    ReDim arrReturns(1 To TotRows, 1 To TotCols)

    For RowCtr = 1 To TotRows
        For Colctr = 1 To TotCols
            arrReturns(RowCtr, Colctr) = Val(Returns.Cells(RowCtr, Colctr).Value)
        Next
    Next


    ReDim arrWeights(1 To WgtRows, 1 To 1)


    For WgtColctr = 1 To WgtRows

        arrWeights(WgtColctr) = Val(Weights.Cells(WgtColctr, 1).Value)

    Next


    APortfolioReturnsXL1 = APortfolioReturns(arrReturns(), arrWeights())

     Exit Function

errHandler:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred." & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & CStr(Err.Number)

End Function
```

I am getting an

> error subscript out of range

.

it doesnt enter the loop in the this line:

```
For WgtColctr = 1 To WgtRows

        arrWeights(WgtColctr) = Val(Weights.Cells(WgtColctr, 1).Value)

    Next
```

Comment: `arrWeights` is 2D for starters.

Comment: You don't need a loop to populate an array with a range.

Comment: Use `arrWeights(WgtColctr, 1) = Val(Weights.Cells(WgtColctr, 1).Value)
`

Comment: Thank you all.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign value to a **2D array**.

**Use:** `arrWeights(WgtColctr, 1) = Val(Weights.Cells(WgtColctr, 1).Value)`

**Instead of:** `arrWeights(WgtColctr) = Val(Weights.Cells(WgtColctr, 1).Value)`